# .htaccess from dynamic page url to static with variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic-url

I want to create a dynamic rule (possibly of the .htaccess) to redirect the page from:

```
https://www.example.com/dir/search?q=stack+overflow
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/dir/stack-overflow
```

I'm aware I need to have a `/dir` folder

I tried with this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\. search?q=$1
```

Not working.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a 301 redirect from `/dir/search?q=stack-overflow` to `/dir/stack-overflow`, that is if a user enters `https://www.example.com/dir/search?q=stack-overflow` the browser URL will change to `https://www.example.com/dir/stack-overflow`. The question is, is `/dir/stack-overflow` a real folder or file? I don't thinks so and therefor you have to rewrite `/dir/stack-overflow` back to `/dir/search?q=stack-overflow`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/?dir/search/?$ /dir/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?dir/search/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?dir/([^/?]+)/?$ /dir/search?q=$1 [L]
```

I you don't want to rewrite back than delete the last two lines.